# Как вернуть значение из функции?

Tags: ios, swift

Как правильно вернуть/получить значение `response` из функции?

```
 class func wallGet() {
    VK.API.Wall.get([VK.Arg.ownerId : "-1", VK.Arg.filter : "postponed"]).send(
        onSuccess: {response in print("SwiftyVK: wall.get success \n \(response)")},
        onError: {error in print("SwiftyVK: wall.get fail \n \(error)")})
 }
```

Блоки `onSuccess`, `onError` имеют тип `(JSON) -> ()`

Comment: не очень знаю swift, но дело даже не в нем. Вам нужна возможность выполнить код синхронно. Возможно вам поможет rx

Comment: Я бы написал VKWallObservable (в java), который выполняется синхронно и постит в onNext респонс. Вопрос в том, что это блокирующая операция и не стоит делать такие функции в (кажется в ios это называется так) Grand Central

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вернуть функцию в параметрах, вот так:

```swift
 class func wallGet(onSuccess: (JSON) -> Void, onError: (JSON) -> Void) {
    VK.API.Wall.get([VK.Arg.ownerId : "-1", VK.Arg.filter : "postponed"]).send(
        onSuccess: { response in
          onSuccess(response)
        },
        onError: {error in
          onError(error)
        })
 }
```

Использование wallGet:

```
A.wallGet(onSuccess: { response in 
   //действия с респонсом
   }, onError: { error in
   //обработка ошибки
})
```

Еще можно использовать систему промисов:
https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit

Конечно, можно просто сделать структуру по типу такой:

```
struct Result {
   var response: JSON?
   var error: Error?
}
//И затем возвращать структуру в каждом из случаев.
return Result(response: response, error: nil)
//Или
return Result(response: nil, error: error)
//И проверять ее поля:
if result.response != nil {
  //Использование респонса
} else {
  //Обработка ошибки
}
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Код представленный Вами не предполагает синхронного исполнения (т.е. вернуть что-то из функции нельзя, да она ничего и не возвращает кроме void). Вызовы (кложи), которые даны в качестве параметров onSuccess и onError асинхронные. Обработать ответ, полученный в результате GET запроса можно в одном из двух колбеков, которые будут вызваны несколько позже. Welcome to асинхронный мир. Если таки Вам надо превратить асинхронный вызов в синхронный, то для этих целей можно например использовать вложенный run loop, но это совсем другая история.

Например, запустите ниже приведенный код в Playground и Вы увидите что значение переменной result появится секунд через 10 после того, как в логе сначала появится надпись "Request started!"

```
let result:String = DispatchQueue(label: "background").sync {
    let loop = RunLoop.current
    var resultValue:String? = nil
    print("Request started!")
    DispatchQueue.global(qos:   DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10 , execute: {
    resultValue = "Response received!" })
    loop.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 12))
    return resultValue!
}

print ("Result is: ", result)
```

Можно вызывать вложенный runLoop в цикле и проверять не получен ли результат в другом потоке.

```
var loopCount = 100
let loop = RunLoop.current
repeat {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(loopCount)
        loopCount -= 1
    }
    loop.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))
} while loopCount > 0
```

В этом случае DispatchQueue.main.async запускает код в конце основного run loop и всякий раз вложенный runLoop останавливает главный поток на 0.1 секунды, чтобы обработать поступившие асинхронно ответы.

Еще один вариант перехода к синхронному выполнению асинхронного кода
дает использование семафора

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
var loopCount = 100

DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).asyncAfter (deadline: .now() + 1 , execute: {
    repeat{
     loopCount -= 1
     print("loopCount = \(loopCount)")
    }  while loopCount > 0
    semaphore.signal()
})

_ = semaphore.wait(timeout:DispatchTime.distantFuture)

print("Final loopCount = \(loopCount)")
```

Соответственно поместив асинхронный код в аналогичную обертку можно именно вернуть значение. Но делать это я крайне не советую, так как если Вы запустите такой код в основном потоке, где крутиться UI, Вы просто "заморозите" основной поток, что приведет к "тормозам" в UI.
Обработку результата запроса нужно проводить именно внутри кложи onSuccess, а обработку ошибки в onError.